# getFullYear() of an object

Tags: javascript, date, object

Not sure about the heading but I have a problem with an object literal value. I have an object named 'person' with first-, lastname, nationality and born. When I initialize this I carry some values in to the object and the 'born'-value comes in form of 'YYYY-MM-DD' But I have to present with the full year, 'YYYY'.

```
let person = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    nationality: '',
    born: '',

    print3: function() {
    return 'My name is ' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName + ' from ' + this.nationality + '.' + ' I was born ' + this.born + '.';
    },

    init: function(firstName, lastName, nationality, born) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.nationality = nationality;
        this.born = born;
    }
};
```

The init:

```
person2.init('Henri', 'Becquerel', 'France', '1852-12-15')
```

Expected outcome should be:

```
"My name is Henri Becquerel from France. I was born 1852."
```

I know I have to use the .getFullYear-function somewhere in the code but I have tried all the places I can think of and I'm out of ideas.

Regards

Comment: get first 4 chars of `born`: `born.slice(0, 4)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Date()` will parse a string in ISO 8601 format like you have. So your `init()` function can save a date object instead of the string. Then you can call `getFullYear()` on `this.born`:

```js
let person = {
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  nationality: '',
  born: '',

  print3: function() {
    return 'My name is ' + this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName + ' from ' + this.nationality + '.' + ' I was born ' + this.born.getFullYear() + '.';
  },

  init: function(firstName, lastName, nationality, born) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.nationality = nationality;
    this.born = new Date(born);  // create a Date object
  }
};

person.init('Henri', 'Becquerel', 'France', '1852-12-15')
console.log(person.print3())
```

Comment: Dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD format are parsed as UTC, so in some cases the year will be different to the local year, e.g. for someone in New York USA `new Date('2018-01-01').getFullYear()` returns 2017. Parsing the string to a date then using a method to get back the year is a lot more work and potentially error prone. Simply slicing the first four digits (using any of *substr*, *substring*, *slice*, *split*, etc.) is much simpler and avoids the vagaries of built-in parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an instance of the date and call getFullYear() on it.

that would then be: new Date('1852-12-15').getFullYear()